# Multiple shadow layer with 9-patch?

Tags: android, layer, shadow, nine-patch

I am trying to achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSYCR.png) look on my buttons. I have tried couple of things but none of them worked. My last solution is to create 9-patch images (one image for top-left light shadow layer, and another one for right-bottom dark shadow layer) and combining them within a draw-able resource file. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/solids">
    <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/bottom" android:dither="false" />
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/solid">
    <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/shadow1" android:dither="false" />
</item>

</layer-list>
```

But they are not fitting right. They look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iObb4.png) :/ Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Edit: Also i need another 9-patch drawables for my cardviews. In my design, there is a card like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uTRb.png). I got details about this card from Adobe xd [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eBF6.png), when i do it like exactly what it says, it is not fitting right. İt becomes like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1osXb.png) How can i fix it?

Edit 2: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8cff.png) is my 9-patch file for the cardview. And here how i use it:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/myCard"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/card1"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.25"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.512"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/card1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card1"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.90">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/myNinePatch"/>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

note: I am not a native speaker so i have tried to explain it best that i can.

Comment: I do not get the need for "layers". A single image is more than enough (for each supported screen density).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When i use an image, there is so many empty spaces around the image. Because of that, my components seems too small.

Comment: you can parametrize padding in 9-patch, check out in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawables#nine-patch). also remember to set `android:padding` for your `View`s with 9patch background set

Comment: Hi @snachmsm thanks for the reply. Can you provide me some code, because i didnt understand what i should make different. I used this [link](https://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/) to create 9 patch shadows.

Comment: just fill empty space in the middle of picture with your color and you will get one image, no need to make `layer-list` in here

Comment: but i want my button have a white shadow on top-left and a darker shadow on bottom-right. Wouldn't it be have only one shadow if i do it like what you said?

Comment: @snachmsm can you also look at the edit part, i just uploaded it :/ thank you

Comment: it looks like wrongly formed 9patch - framework isn't recognising properly content and stretch areas... post some code how do you attach it to view and 9patch file itself

Comment: @snachmsm i add 9-patch file and how i use it. Can you take a look at it

Comment: You do not need layers. In the end, what you see is ONE COMBINED PICTURE. Therefore, just go for a single image and make a 9 patch out of it. Just as simple as that.

Comment: @Phantômaxx but then how can i get the top white shadow and the bottom dark shadow at the same time?

Comment: The shadows themeselves are part of the image. NOT separate layers.

Comment: @Phantômaxx what i dont understand is how to create an image like that :( if you are free rn can you make a sample for me please? I am too new to android and i really really want to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: A free photo/image editor will do the trick (simply merge all the layes together and save as PNG - ARGB). Maybe you should study how a 9 patch actually works. Nothing too fancy, it requires just a little of trial and error. Mind the transparency.